# Geckodriver error: "FirefoxWebElement has no len()"

Tags: python, selenium, spyder, geckodriver

I installed geckodriver since selenium is no longer compatible with recent versions of Firefox. Please note that I am using Spyder on a Mac. Before, I had successfully scraped data from a website, but once I switched to geckodriver, I had to make modifications to the script. For example,

```
 browser.find_by_id('closeMessageButton').click()
```

is now

```
 browser.find_element_by_id('closeMessageButton').click()
```

I modified the following:

```
prov_count = len(browser.find_by_id("j_id48:j_id49:j_id108:cmbSecimCevresi").first.find_by_tag('option'))-1
```

to:

```
prov_count = len(browser.find_element_by_id("j_id48:j_id49:j_id108:cmbSecimCevresi").find_element_by_tag_name('option'))-1
```

but I get the following error: "TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()"

I am trying to get the count of the list on the following website and so I can loop through the list under "*Il adi": https://sonuc.ysk.gov.tr/module/sspsHalkoylamasiYeni.jsf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `.find_elements_by_tag_name()`... the plural version (notice the "s" in "elements"). The singular version you are using will only return one element and does not have a length (`len`).

Comment: Many thanks. And, do you know how I can modify the code "browser.select('j_id48:j_id49:j_id108:cmbSecimCevresi',iller[j].value)"? I had used this before, but now with geckodriver I'm getting the error: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: I'd have to see more of the code. That shouldn't have worked in the old FF driver either unless there was some text missing from copy/paste, etc. Put that in a new question and I'll look out for it or someone else will answer it.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted it as a new question.